# jQuery: Scale entire div with its children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scale, shrink

is it somehow possible to use jQuery or Javascript to scale an entire div down to 70%. E.g. I have a horizontal slider with images. On smaller screens the slider with all its images (and their captions) should be like 70% of it's original size. It's really difficult though do shrink everything manually with jquery and remember all the original sizes.

Any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: If you need to alter the styles for a site on smaller screens, [`@media` queries](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) are a good way to do this for browsers that support them

Comment: I guess that using CSS fluid techniques are out of the question?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find inspiration from:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/

A zoomer that can zoom forth and back a generic html content, made in jQuery by a famous web designer.